# Indus river and Hinduism

Tags: mahabharata, scripture, tradition, ganga, sindhu

What do ancient scriptures, texts and traditions tell us about the river Indus (Sindhu)?

Are there references to the Indus River Civilisation in the Mahabharata?

Has there been a significance of Indus like Ganga?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rigveda Mandala 10 Shuktha 75](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-x/suktha-li-to-c/suktha-75) describes Sindhu river.

> 1. Waters, the worshipper addresses to you excellent praise in the dwelling of the institutor of the rite; they flowed by sevens through
>    the three (worlds); but the Sindhu surpasses (all) the (other) streams
>    in strength.
> 2. For your course, Sindhu, Varuna tore open a path, since you hastened towards food; you go by a lofty road down upon the earth, by
>    which (road) you reign in the sight of all worlds.
> 3. The sound goeth forth in heaven above the earth; (Sindhu) with shining wave animates his endless speed; as rains issue thundering
>    from the cloud, so Sindhu (thunders) when he advances roaring like a
>    bull.
> 4. Like mothers crying for their sons (the other rivers) hasten towards you, Sindhu, like milch cows with their milk; you lead your
>    two wings like a king going to battle when you march in the van of the
>    streams that are descending (with you).
> 5. Accept this my praise, Ganga, Yamuna, Sarasvati, Sutudri, Parusni, Marudvedha with Asikni, and Vitasta,
> 6. You, Sindhu, in order to reach the swift-rnoving Gomati, have united, yourself first with the Trstama: (now be united) with the
>    Susartu, the Rasa, the Sveti, the Kubha, and the Mehatnu, in
>    conjunction with which streams you do advance. listen, Arjikiya with
>    SuSoma.
> 7. Straight-flowing,white-coloured,bright-shining(Sindhu) bear along in its might the rapid waters; the inviolable sindhu, the most
>    efficacious of the efficacious, is speckled like a mare' beautiful as
>    a handsome woman.
> 8. The sindhu is rich in horses, rich in chariots, rich in clothes, rich in gold ornaments, well-made, rich in food, rich in wool, ever
>    fresh, alounding in Silama plants, and the auspicious river wears
>    honey-growing (flowers).